# can't find variable indexeddb in react native without debugger

Tags: react-native, remote-debugging, indexeddb

I have a file call mydb.js

```
import { openDB, deleteDB, wrap, unwrap } from 'idb';

const dbPromise = openDB('mydb-store', 1, {
  upgrade(db) {
    db.createObjectStore('keyval');
  }
});

export const getItemAsync = async key => {
  return (await dbPromise).get('keyval', key);
};

export const setItemAsync = async (key, val) => {
  return (await dbPromise).put('keyval', val, key);
};

export const deleteItemAsync = async key => {
  return (await dbPromise).delete('keyval', key);
};

export const clear = async () => {
  return (await dbPromise).clear('keyval');
};

export const keys = async () => {
  return (await dbPromise).getAllKeys('keyval');
};
```

in another file I am calling

```
import * as MyDB from '../api/mydb';

deviceId = await MyDB.setItemAsync('deviceId', uuidv4());
```

For some strange reason, if I have remote debugging on, everything works fine.  As soon as I turn off debugging, I am getting an error

Can't find variable: indexedDB
openDB
index.js: 15:30
blah blah blah

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you `await`ing the result?

Comment: yes, deviceId = await MyDB.setItemAsync('deviceId', uuidv4());

Answer (score 0):

After some research, it appears that react-native does not yet support indexeddb.  Hopefully it will soon.